# Can project Tango java run on normal tablet

Tags: google-project-tango

I was trying to compile the given folder ***tango-examples-java-master*** given on developer site of google. I was unable to run the **java_quick_start_example folder**. It says i have  a missing **libtango_support_api.so** 
Although i have it in my jinLib Folder. I was trying to run this app on my normal tablet. Do i need to have google tango tablet for running that example ? because seeing that particular code i dont think we require google tango tablet for that. Can anyone clear my doubt.. it has been bugging me a lot for past few days

Comment: The Tango client and support API are developed for Tango devices only. Therefore you can not use the example codes on other devices.

Comment: I agree with your explanation @bashbug .. But i have a small doubt even though i have incorporated libtango_client_api.so in my Jinlib folder why does it show that libtango_client_api.so is missing. shouldn't it show some error like device incompatible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot run this with non-Tango device.

1. The java interface is loading the .so from tango core path rather than application path. So placing the .so in the application lib folder doesn't really help the jar library to link against it.
2. Tango requires extra sensors to run the algorithm. It's only supported on Tango device now.